# Python flask webpage trying to create a single item details page from multiple products

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I am doing a flask website project and im trying to get create an individual item page for each of my items. Im using sqlite for the database.

Below is the html code

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block main %}
<!-- display products for the different categories stock -->
<section>

    <div class="text-dark text-center">
        <div>
            <p class="h3 text-dark mb-4">New Arrival</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card-deck">
        <!-- each product is a bootstrap card -->
        {% for product in products%}
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{url_for('static', filename='img/'+product.image)}}" alt="Card image">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">{{product.name}}</h4>
                <p class="card-text">{{product.description}}</p>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">


                <form action="{{ url_for('main.order') }}">
                    <input type="hidden" id="product_id" name="product_id" value="{{ product.id }}">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
                </form>  

                <div class="card-footer"><a href= "{{ url_for('main.itemdetails', productid=product.id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Item Details</a></div>





            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

</section>
{% endblock %}
```

using route

```
@bp.route('/<int:productid>/')
def itemdetails():
    products= Product.query.one('productid')
    return render_template('itemdetails.html', products = products)
```

my itemdetails.html page:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block main %}
>
    <div class="text-dark text-center">
        <div>
            <p class="h3 text-dark mb-4" id="cities_anchor">Available Products</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-deck">

        {% for product in products%}
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{url_for('static', filename='img/'+product.image)}}" alt="Card image">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">{{product.name}}</h4>
                <p class="card-text">{{product.description}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer"> 
                <form action="{{ url_for('main.order') }}">
                <input type="hidden" id="product_id" name="product_id" value="{{ product.id }}">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
                </form>  
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

getting error message
TypeError: itemdetails() got an unexpected keyword argument 'productid'

The problem is i need a interactive item details that only shows information of the product that the user was clicked on. How can i do that?

My Database

```
from . import db

class Stock(db.Model):
    __tablename__='stocks'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
    image = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False, default = 'barbel.jpg')
    products = db.relationship('Product', backref='Stock', cascade="all, delete-orphan")

    def __repr__(self):
        str = "Id: {}, Name: {}, Description: {}, Image: {}\n" 
        str =str.format( self.id, self.name,self.description,self.image)
        return str

orderdetails = db.Table('orderdetails', 
    db.Column('order_id', db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('orders.id'), nullable=False),
    db.Column('product_id',db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('products.id'),nullable=False),
    db.PrimaryKeyConstraint('order_id', 'product_id') )

class Product(db.Model):
    __tablename__='products'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64),nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
    image = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    price = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    stock_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('stocks.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        str = "Id: {}, Name: {}, Description: {}, Image: {}, Price: {}, Stock: {}, Date: {}\n" 
        str =str.format( self.id, self.name,self.description,self.image, self.price, self.stock_id, self.date)
        return str

class Order(db.Model):
    __tablename__='orders'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    status = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(64))
    phone = db.Column(db.String(32))
    email = db.Column(db.String(128))
    address = db.Column(db.String(128))
    postcode = db.Column(db.String(32))
    city = db.Column(db.String(32))
    state = db.Column(db.String(32))
    totalcost = db.Column(db.Float)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    products = db.relationship("Product", secondary=orderdetails, backref="orders")

    def __repr__(self):
        str = "id: {}, Status: {}, Firstname: {}, Phone: {}, Email: {}, Address: {}, Postcode: {}, City: {}, State: {},  Date: {}, Products: {}, Total Cost: {}\n" 
        str =str.format( self.id, self.status,self.firstname,self.phone, self.email, self.address, self.postcode, self.city, self.state, self.date, self.products, self.totalcost)
        return str
```

Comment: In your view, you don't pass in the argument. Change it to def itemdetails(productid): and in your query, change 'productid' to productid without the string. See if that helps.

Comment: no its not working

Comment: You do have the accepted requests up in your view, right? ['POST', 'GET']?

Comment: yes i have in views.py

Comment: TypeError: itemdetails() got an unexpected keyword argument 'productid'

Comment: You did put the productid in the function parameter right? Like def itemdetails(productid): ?

Comment: @bp.route('/<int:productid>/')
def itemdetails(productid):
    products= Product.query.one(productid)
    return render_template('itemdetails.html', products = products)

Answer (score 0):

With our seeing your Database Schema I am not 100% sure, but I would bet that you need to change productId to just id.

EDIT:

After looking at the Models that you posted you do not have a productid in the model.  You do have an id.  Change productId to id and that should solve your issue.

Comment: I have posted my Database, I would appreciate if you could help

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect that it is confirmed there is no productid just id.

Comment: can i add a new productid variable to the Product class instead of changing id to productid will that work?

Comment: You can try doing productid = id in the model but I am not sure that will work.

Answer (score 0):

For that particular error the fix is that you need to provide the keyword argument `productid` like this:

```
@bp.route('/<int:productid>/')
def itemdetails(productid=None):
    #           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    products= Product.query.filter(id==productid).first()
    #                                  ^^^^^^^^^
    return render_template('itemdetails.html', products = products)
```

And then notice how it's the variable `productid` and not the string that's being passed to the query.

Comment: Hi i am getting this error after changing it as you mentioned AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: main.itemdetails

Comment: You have to use this function, and delete the old one. You can't have the two of them.

Comment: did as you told me but getting the error TypeError: one() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.  should i use any specific query and i attached my database above also, is there any changes i need to make.

Comment: @Jonesray: I changed the query. Please see edited answer.

Comment: I am getting this error after changing the route  as you mentioned def itemdetails(productid=None):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: i corrected the indentation error and run it  but when i click the item details get message "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"